# How to get hashtag from string that contains # at the beginning and end without space at the end?

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

This is my string

```
"I made this wonderful pic last #chRistmas... #instagram #nofilter #snow #fun"
```

and I would like to get hashtag that contains # at the beginning and end without space. My expected result is:

```
$fun
```

This is what I have so far for regex search:

```
#[a-z0-9]+
```

but it give me all the hashtags not the one that I want. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `#[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` instead of your current regex

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to match a hashtag at the end of the string, or the last hashtag in the string. So, there are several ways solve the issue.

## Matching the last hashtag in the string

```
let str = "I made this wonderful pic last #chRistmas... #instagram #nofilter #snow #fun"
let regex = "#[[:alnum:]]++(?!.*#[[:alnum:]])"
if let range = str.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) {
    let text: String = String(str[range])
    print(text)
}
```

**Details**

- `#` - a hash symbol
- `[[:alnum:]]++` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?!.*#[[:alnum:]])` - no `#` + 1+ alphanumeric chars after any 0+ chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current  location.

## Matching a hashtag at the end of the string

Same code but with the following regexps:

```
let regex = "#[[:alnum:]]+$"
```

or

```
let regex = "#[[:alnum:]]+\\z"
```

Note that `\z` matches the very end of string, if there is a newline char between the hashtag and the end of string, there won't be any match (in case of `$`, there will be a match).

**Note on the regex**

If a hashtag should only start with a letter, it is a better idea to use

```
#[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

where `[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter and `[[:alnum:]]*` matches 0+ letters or/and digits.

Note that in ICU regex patterns, you may write `[[:alnum:]]` as `[:alnum:]`.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`(^#[a-z0-9]+|#[a-z0-9]+$)`

Test it [online](https://regex101.com/r/CnaLcb/1)